# Could not find file or assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms' when deploying via ClickOnce from another project

Tags: c#, winforms, clickonce, cefsharp

I have a solution that has multiple Winforms projects. Project1 is the main project, and Project2 is the project that uses CefSharp. Project1 references Project2. Project1.exe launches Project2.exe to show the browser. I am deploying Project1 via ClickOnce. I am using the latest version of CefSharp (85.3.13).

Everything works great when debugging. If I set Project2 as the startup project, and deploy it via ClickOnce, everything works great. The problem is though, if deploying Project2, CefSharp will not work on Project1. I just get the following error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.WinForms'... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

or sometimes

```
Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core'... or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

My solution looks like this:

```
Solution
  Project1 <--winforms project that contains CefSharp browser
  Project2 <--Winforms project Deployed via ClickOnce, references Project1
```

The settings on both projects are identical. All the Application Files are correctly listed on both projects (using a.targets file and importing it on the .csproj file).

I even tried installing the c++ runtime. Nothing works. When I open the folder location of the ClicOnce install in ../local/apps/2.0/..., all the necessary cefsharp dll's are there.

Is there something special I need to do in order to get this to work? Is it possible to run CefSharp from a separate project than is being deployed via ClickOnce?

Comment: Does your app work if you copy it to the target machine directly? What version of .Net are you targeting? I generally avoid click once as it's difficult to debug when things aren't working. Have you tried directly installing CefSharp Nuget packages into both projects?

Comment: https://msbuildlog.com is helpful in understanding what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @amaitland I am actually just trying to get it to work by installing it on my dev machine for now, and yes if I just run the project1.exe from the bin/debug folder, it works perfect. I am targeting 4.5.2. Yea I am losing faith in ClickOnce, but unfortunately this is an existing app deployed to 100's of computers so don't really want to change that now. And also yes, I installed the Nuget packages to both projects. Thanks for thet tip, I'll check out msbuildlog.com

Comment: As you are targeting. Net 4.5.2 the most likely cause is not all the files have been included by the installer. Try copying the bin folder into the  folder click once installed to.

Comment: you got me on the right track @amaitland, turns out it was the exe.config file for the secondary project that was not being copied. This file is needed by CefSharp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error message is a bit misleading, as the problem wasn't any of the cefsharp related files that were missing.

The problem was the secondary project's exe.config file was not being deployed. This file is needed by cefsharp which was causing the error to be thrown. I simply added the exe.config file as an existing item to the primary project I am deploying. Now it works perfectly.